# AS3 curved line animation

Tags: actionscript-3, flash

[image: picture]

I want to create animation of curved line in as3 as it is shown in image. But I have not idea how to do this.

I can create first and last picture of animation by drawing api and curveTo method. But dont know how to do images between!

First curve on picture:

```
line.graphics.moveTo(10, 200);
line.graphics.lineStyle(15);
line.graphics.curveTo(210,0,410, 200);
```

I tryed draw states between in drawing editor.

Is there any way to create states between by using drawing api ?

Thanks for any advice.

Comment: If you don't mind, I would like to give you hints: for animation you will need time and Timer or ENTER_FRAME. And for complex curves, you will need 2 moving dots as start and finish, rules to predefine path for example Bezier, and bunch of helper methods to find points on path.

Comment: Seams like the line in your example image is following a sine curve! Can't you use this to get your points? ;)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

As **@NicolasSiver** mentioned using an `ENTER_FRAME` is definitely an option when performing this kind of task. **@Chadyk** mentioned your curve does look like it's the sine curve. So one way you could implement this for some flexible adjustments:

Set some variables so you can adjust things like, radius, position, and size of the curve:

```
private var origin:Point;
private var degree:int;
private var curveSize:int = 25; //radius
private var curveLength:int = 200;
```

Then set it up with an `ENTER_FRAME`:

```
//set the origin to whatever you like, i'm choosing the center from the center of the curve
origin = new Point( stage.stageWidth/2 - curveLength/2, stage.stageHeight/2 );

//create our sprite     
sprite = new Sprite();
sprite.graphics.lineStyle( 2, 0xFF0000 );
sprite.graphics.moveTo( origin.x, origin.y );
addChild(sprite);

//add the listener      
addEventListener( Event.ENTER_FRAME, drawCurve );
```

Then it's pretty straight forward, we will increment the degree/rotation, apply the basic trig function solving for the y position, and follow our origin as it moves along the x axis:

```
public function drawCurve( e:Event ):void {
    if ( origin.x >= origin.x + curveLength ) {
        removeEventListener( Event.ENTER_FRAME, drawCurve );
        return;
    }
    degree += 2;
    sprite.graphics.lineTo( ++origin.x, origin.y + curveSize * Math.sin( degree * Math.PI / 180 ) );
}
```